# Implementing DCC GARCH Model with External Regressors in R

Tags: r, garch

I am trying to estimate a DCC GARCH model with an external regressor in the DCC equation. However, the external regressor option in the `rmgarch` package is for the VAR option. Is there any way I can include the external regressor please?

Comment: I guess you can include external regressors when defining the univariate models via `rugarch` (which has to be done before defining and fitting the DCC part), can you not?

Comment: In this case, I am looking to extract the dynamic correlation coefficients on the basis of the impact of the external variable. Whereas in ugarch I am specifying on the basis of one variable.

Comment: So you want an external regressor in the DCC equation? I have not heard of an implementation that does that. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Actually I will be extracting the dynamic covariances from the DCC model. I am trying to ascertain If, in the wake of the exogenous variable, there are changes in the covariances or to put simply is there any difference in the spillover in the presence of the exogenous variable. I also could not come across anywhere regarding adding an exogenous to a DCC Garch Model.

Comment: DCC is not suitable for modelling spillovers, as the volatility of each series only depends on its *own* past via a univariate GARCH model. DCC only models *contemporaneous* relationships the between time series, while a spillover suggests time-lagged effects. Perhaps BEKK-GARCH would be a more relevant model for your purposes.

Comment: Actually I stand corrected and thank you for that. I am looking at the contemporaneous relationship, and spill over is secondary. Particularly the dynamic correlation and the covariances during times affected by the exogenous variable.

Comment: Still, I think what you are trying to do might be quite difficult. A simpler solution might be  to obtain the fitted conditional correlations and covariances and then regress them on your external variable of interest. Perhaps less elegant, but much more doable :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Richard Hardy. I had actually done this on an ARIMA model, using the exogenous variable (covariance output from the DCC GARCH model). But it makes total sense to use regression as you have suggested, because it is the contemporaneous relation that I am studying and not a lagged one.

Comment: Well, regression with or without ARMA errors does not make a great difference conceptually (if we are interested on the regression part), so if the errors might be autocorrelated, allowing for ARMA errors in the model can help. My interpretation of your previous comments suggests you may want the fitted correlations to be the dependent variable, not the regressor.

Comment: Yes true, the fitted correlations/covariances to be the dependent variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a software implementation of the DCC model with an external regressor in the DCC equation. A simpler solution might be to obtain the fitted conditional correlations and covariances from a vanilla DCC model and then regress them on your external variable of interest. This is not nearly as elegant a solution, but much easier to implement.